# How to build AAB file for Google play from an ionic 3 project

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, google-play-console

I've been trying to build an AAB file from my ionic 3 project but it keeps failing. I've tried Buildtools and it requested for APKs zip file which i have no idea what it is. how do i do this please